# coordinates of 3D contours in python

Tags: python, contour

Thanks to the knowledge acquired on this website. I am able to write a simple script that prints the coordinate (x and y) of a contour plot.

Here is an example:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

# generate a set of random points
npts = 500
phi = random(npts)*2*pi

theta = random(npts)*pi
u = random(npts)

x = u * sin( theta) * cos( phi )
y = u * sin( theta) * sin( phi )
z = u * cos( theta )
bins = linspace(-1,1,100)

H = histogram2d(x,y,bins=(bins,bins))

fig=figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

levels = [1,2,3]

CS = ax1.contour(H[0].T,levels=levels)

show()

# print contours coordinates
for kk in range(len(levels)):
    print CS.allsegs[kk][0][:,0],CS.allsegs[kk][0][:,1]
```

I would like to do the same, but in 3D but I'm struggling.

The first step to do is to bin the data, which I can do with:

```
H = histogramdd((x,y,z),bins=(bins,bins,bins))
```

But now, how can I get the coordinates of a contour in 3D? I can't even come up with a simple algorithm for that.